# Python Grouping and assigning values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have 2 questions:

1. I need to generate the column ID where in 'ID_' remains constant and for every group in column B a unique id is generated. How can I do this in python?
2. in addition, whenever the program is executed for the next time with new data, I want to generate the ids where it has to trigger from end of previous id. Could someone provide me with a solution?

Thanks:)

Required output for question 1

```
Column A        Column B        ID
A               123             ID_01
A               123             ID_01
A               123             ID_01
A               456             ID_02
A               456             ID_02
B               988             ID_03
B               988             ID_03
B               233             ID_04
B               233             ID_04
B               654             ID_05
B               654             ID_05
B               654             ID_05
```

Required output for question 2

```
Column A        Column B        ID
C               567             ID_06
C               567             ID_06
C               567             ID_06
C               098             ID_07
C               098             ID_07
C               200             ID_08
D               111             ID_09
D               123             ID_10
D               123             ID_10
D               450             ID_11
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use groupby with cumcount but the issue is it generates continuous numbers for a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) with save maximal number to helper json file, if run again first is read json for last maximal value:

```
import json

file = 'last.json'

#create file with content:
#{"last": 0}
with open(file) as f:
    last = json.load(f)['last']
print (last)

g = df.groupby(['Column A','Column B'], sort=False).ngroup().add(1).add(last)

with open(file, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump({'last': g.max()}, f)

df['ID'] = g.astype(str).str.zfill(2).radd('ID_')
print (df)
```